# How to implement double tap zooming in Mupdf?

Tags: android, mupdf

I'm researching Mupdf library on Android.
I compiled and ran the Sample successfully. 
It's really a great library.
But now I have a problem with zooming the page when firing "Double tap" event.

First, I implemented my View to 'listen' double tap event :

```
public class MuPDFReaderView extends ReaderView implements GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener
```

Then, I overrode `onDoubleTap()` method :

```
@Override
public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    MuPDFView pageView = (MuPDFView) getDisplayedView();
    pageView.setScale(1.5f);
    Log.e("double tap", "" + e.getDownTime());
    return false;
}
```

When double tap on page, I can see the "double tap" log in Logcat, but the page is not zoomed. What was I wrong here?

Comment: Hello, have you figured how to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why your attempt didn't worked, but here's another way to do it:

Instead of implementing the `GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener` on your View, implement it directly on the `ReaderView` you extended

```
public class ReaderView extends AdapterView<Adapter> implements 
    GestureDetector.OnGestureListener,
    GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener,
    ScaleGestureDetector.OnScaleGestureListener,
    Runnable { ... }
```

and then override the `OnDoubleTap` method like this

```
@Override
public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {

    float previousScale = mScale;
    mScale += (mScale == 1f) ? 2f : -2f;
    float factor = mScale/previousScale;

    View v = mChildViews.get(mCurrent);
    if (v != null) {
        // Work out the focus point relative to the view top left
        int viewFocusX = (int)e.getX() - (v.getLeft() + mXScroll);
        int viewFocusY = (int)e.getY() - (v.getTop() + mYScroll);
        // Scroll to maintain the focus point
        mXScroll += viewFocusX - viewFocusX * factor;
        mYScroll += viewFocusY - viewFocusY * factor;
        requestLayout();
    }

    return true;
}
```

Also you will have to override these 2 other methods

```
@Override
public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent e) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
    return false;
}
```

Got this code from the Librelio Android example

https://github.com/libreliodev/android

Comment: I added above methods to ReaderView class,but its not working Double click yet? when i add above code it says  "The method onDoubleTap(MotionEvent) of type ReaderView must override or implement a supertype method" Do i have to add above method to somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle this via ReaderView. Modify the scale and initiate request layout.